# Working papers in Bibdesk

Tags: bibtex, sorting

Is there a way to create a working paper in Bibdesk?

Bibdesk does not the option of working paper and it cannot be modified to from @article to @workingpaper in the latex itself and then opened up in bibdesk again.

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: Hi, i am not quite sure what you are asking for. Are you asking for a new type `workingpaper` that you can use just like `article`, `book` or `online` to cite in your LaTeX document?

Comment: Hi, yes I think so. There are options for @Book{abramowitz+stegun, ... @article{abramowitz+stegun} @inbook and so on, but there is not one for working papers themselves that can be cited in the LaTex document. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create new entry types in bib desk, just go to Preferences and then Fields and click on `Custom BibTeX and Fields (edit)` and then  click the + under `Type`.

[image]

After that the new types are available when you create or edit existing of new records:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant that works fantastically. Thanks Guido